# Is it possible to invert colours in a gradient in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to invert colours in a gradient in Illustrator (CC 2014)?

When I try Edit > Edit Colours > Invert Colours on the box that I want inverted, it tells me "Colors Note: No invertible colors found."

I'd like to get this effect around my text, where the background is inverted. Is it maybe possible using a filter? I suspect I might have to move to Photoshop for that...

[image: inverting colors]

Answer (score 1):

The most common option to invert gradient is Reverse Gradient option -

[image]

You can apply the same gradient as was used in the background and reverse it via this tool.

Comment: Hmmm... wouldn't that just flip the gradient, so that my blue goes where the yellow is, and vice versa? I'm not sure that would work because it's not the same as inverting. Inverting gives the opposite colour, whereas flipping only gives the colour on the other side of the gradient. You can see from my sample image that the red behind the first lines is not the same as the red in my gradient... Right?

Comment: @I'am afraid that inverting won't work in your case. Will check this later

Answer (score 1):

`Edit > Edit Colors > Invert Colors` works on gradients.

[image]

If you find it is not working, you'll need to examine your object further to determine why **your** gradient isn't working - are you selecting a mask rather than a filled object? Is there an appearance stack and you aren't targeting the fill properly? Are you trying to invert a raster image? Etc.. The feature *does* work on gradients.

Comment: hmm thanks. that's good to know. i'll have to work it some more and see where i'm going wrong. i actually did [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mB_0EpoKsU), creating a rectangle, clipping a part of the background away.

Comment: i figured out what was wrong. it couldn't invert my shape because it had colours in it that were 'global'. so i picked the same colour again, this time not from a palette, but the CMYK value and it was fine!